# how can I display my shp correctly with leaflet and geoserver?

Tags: html, leaflet, geoserver

I published my shp layer on geoserver it works well, it is visualized well but at the level of the code not displayed, can you help me please?
code:

```
var app = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8081/geoserver/MyMap/wms?", {
  layers:'MyMap:app',
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true,
  attribution: "app"
});
app.addTo(map);
```

Comment: can you give us some clues? what do you see in the network tab of the debugger? what is the request made? what is the response from GeoServer? does the GeoServer log file say anything?

Comment: now I managed to display it, the problem is that I add the style on geoserver, instead of displaying my shp with the style a wms file download starts

Comment: Open that file and read the error message in it. Fixing that error will allow the map to display

Comment: that's the problem, I can't open this wms file, if not, you can contact me to send you screen shots?

Comment: I think the problem is styling, do I need to change something in the geoserver styles editor? if so how please

Comment: What do you mean by you can't open the file? It is a simple text file

Comment: it's good now i used udig